Applying if-condition for NULL values in QGIS Python Console
I want to create Excel synoptics from shapefiles or PostgreSQL databases.
To know where the start and end points are, I think I need to create logical identifiers for all my entities instead of a simple unique identifier.
So, I set id 0 for the start and want to increment the neighbor to the end.
I've started a script but I'm stuck checking for empty values:
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsGeometry

# Get the "INFRAS" layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('INFRAS')[0]

# Start editing the layer
layer.startEditing()

# Get the index of the field "Id_Infra_s"
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName("Id_Infra_s")

# Iterate through all features of the layer
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    # Get the current value of the field "Id_Infra_s"
    current_value = feature["Id_Infra_s"]
    print(current_value)

    # Check if the value is NULL
    if current_value is None:
        print("An empty value")
    
        # Find neighboring features intersecting with the current feature
        geom = feature.geometry()
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(geom.boundingBox())
    
        for neighbor in layer.getFeatures(request):
            if neighbor.id() != feature.id() and geom.intersects(neighbor.geometry()):
                # Update the Id_Infra of the neighboring feature
                neighbor_value = neighbor['Id_Infra_s']
                new_value = str(int(current_value) + 1)
                print(f"Updating Id_Infra for feature {neighbor.id()} from {neighbor_value} to {new_value}")
                layer.changeAttributeValue(neighbor.id(), idx, new_value)

# Save changes and stop editing
layer.commitChanges()

The exit:
NULL
NULL
0
NULL
NULL
NULL

Why is my if condition not working?

Is it possible that rather than being empty (None) your variable is actually the string "NULL"?

Yes, I tried several possibilities like "NULL" and unfortunately the condition is still false.

QGIS defines a NULL constant in qgis.core. In current versions of QGIS, that is equivalent to a null QVariant (i.e., QVariant()). In future versions (i.e., after the switch to Qt6), it may change to be None.
If you're working in the python console, the NULL constant should already be available. In an external script, import it (from qgis.core import NULL).
Try comparing to NULL instead of None (using == instead of is).

Your condition if current_value is None: fails because it is not working with NULL-values which moreover are of the PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant (qgis.PyQt.QtCore.QVariant) class type.
There are several solutions to solve your issue available:

As, was already noticed by @couteau, the best way to treat NULL-values via Python's not-equal i.e. != comparing operator. Additionally one needs to import the NULL-object i.e. from qgis.core import NULL:
from qgis.core import NULL

if current_value == NULL:
    ...

or using the native operator module:
import operator
from qgis.core import NULL

if operator.eq(current_value, NULL):
    ...


comparing to an empty QVariant() variable:
try:
   from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
except ImportError:
   from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

if current_value == QVariant():
    ...


with the isinstance() function to check if the current_value-object is an instance of the QVariant-class:
try:
   from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
except ImportError:
   from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

if isinstance(current_value, QVariant):
    ...    

This can be easily tested via type(current_value).

employing the not-operator:
if not current_value:
    ...



One could also think of the isNull()-method available for QVariant, however, it will not work for integer values and will evoke the AttributeError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isNull'

However, since QGIS 3.28 one could come up with the QgsVariantUtils class, that includes a method isNull():

Returns true if the specified variant should be considered a NULL
value.
This method is more rigorous vs QVariant::isNull(), which will
return false on newer Qt versions for tests like QVariant( QDateTime() ).isNull().

from qgis.core import QgsVariantUtils

if QgsVariantUtils.isNull(current_value):
    ...

